# Using Node.js as an access point for mobile application API

Tags: node.js, mobile

I'm not sure if I've quite grokked node.js yet, but I really want to implement it, cause what I do understand is pretty friggen sweet.

I've got a mobile application that uses an API from a third party. Users typically open it up to see if anything is new. It occurred to me that so long as I respect the third party API's polling limits (and other restrictions) I could simulate a push based system and allow the user to be notified once something is new.

Basically implement all the API polling from a Node.js server on some sort of interval, and make the mobile app point to my Node.js server instead of the end point API.

#### I figure that this will be good for a number of reasons:

- Takes load off the phone's data usage (since I can cache things on both the phone and the server). This is a huge win for users who have a pay-per-byte data plan
- Allows a central location for storing / accessing all the data
- Lets me do some optimization on the server side (if two users happen to subscribe to the same feed I can get that in one request.

#### I figure this could be bad for a number of reasons:

- If *my* server goes down, then all my apps die. By acting as a go-between my Node.js implementation may very well introduce a higher number of fail points.
- When the third party releases additions to the API, it requires me to implement the changes in two places, instead of one.

My question is this: In general, is this good practice? If not, why?

Comment: If your server goes down, you could fallback to original one (if API conventions are okay with it).

Comment: I can tell you another advantage in doing this: you don't have to make your api key publicly visible.

Comment: Truth be told the client app currently accesses the third party API directly, maintaining both may be a headache to maintain, but it's a noteworthy stop-gap solution for a fall back, at least until major revisions are made to the API in question, at which point I would probably drop client API access stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proxy idea is fine, in that it:

1. converts poll to push
2. insulates the client from API changes
3. allows for some optimizations

I feel only #1 is really important.

Comment: Number 2 is great, but I agree, benefit is in the poll / push conversion